# Objective C: how to resize uitextview height with animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uitextview, uianimation

I have UITextView (textView) in some other view (extView) in my Objective C project with some text in it. The text in textView is quite long so it could by maximised and minimised. Of course, I'd like to do it with some animation.

I change the height of extView with code:

```
- (void)setExtViewHeight:(CGFloat)newHeight withAnimation:(CGFloat)duration
{
    [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                     animations:^
                     {
                         self.extViewHeight.constant = newHeight;
                         [self layoutIfNeeded];
                         [self.textView layoutIfNeeded];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
                     {
                         [self layoutSubviews];
                     }
    ];
}
```

My problem is that animation are actually works only for extView. So when I try to minimise my view the textView jumps to new height and after that extView height is changing with animation. This jump of textView is really annoying and doesn't look good.

What did I do wrong? Why height of textView doesn't follow the animation?

Comment: I am not too familiar with auto-layout (i still prefer autoResizingMasks). If you are resizing extView then you should not have to manually resize the textView too. You should be able to setup the textview such that it retains its distance from the edges. In this case that would be the distance from the bottom. ExtView should then auto-resize its subviews (you may need to enable that too).

Answer (score 0):

Update your autolayout constant outside of the animation block.

Something like this should work.

**Edit: As Duncan C. suggested if you don't want to update the textView height constant as well, you will at least need your textView to have top and bottom relational constraints to your extView**

```
- (void)setExtViewHeight:(CGFloat)newHeight withAnimation:(CGFloat)duration
{
    self.extViewHeight.constant = newHeight;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        [self layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't have self.textViewHeight.constant and I don't like the idea of changing same height two times with only padding difference. So I have only padding constraints from textView to extView and I''d like to do it that way - by changing only extView height.

Comment: If you only want to change one constraint then you'll need to set up other constraints that are dependent on the first. So you'd make your text view's top or bottom position anchored to your "extView". That way when the height of the extView changes, the text view will also change. When you do that simply call layoutIfNeeded on the superView, and don't call layoutIfNeeded on the text view (or call layoutSubviews in the completion block)